# How to align an image in a list ( ul > li ) in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I tried to get the image on the left and the list on the right.
I want this

https://2.pik.vn/2020cfe5742b-09a9-4049-8756-97a93a9f2045.png

But I got this

https://2.pik.vn/2020dcdc684b-ce3b-4b6b-bc00-db421831628f.jpg

```css
h1 {
  color: #ff006e;
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  border: solid;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h1>Flower</h1>
<div>
  <img class="img" width="200" height="200" src="hoa.png" alt="">
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>List 1</span>
      <ul>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>E</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>List 2</span>
      <ul>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>E</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you should add ul margin left:24px because always ul taken spaces for bullet

Answer (score 3):

try like this

```css
h1 {
  color: #ff006e;
  text-align: center;
}
.image{
  float:left;
}
.img {
  border: solid;
  float:left;
}
.content{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Flower</h1>
    <div class="image">
        <img class="img" width="200" height="200" src="hoa.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>List 1</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>B</li>
                    <li>C</li>
                    <li>D</li>
                    <li>E</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>List 2</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>B</li>
                    <li>C</li>
                    <li>D</li>
                    <li>E</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided `float: left` style for the `content` class so it gets overlapped with the `img` class. Providing an `float:left` style for your `content` class will get the desired positioning without overlapping.

```
.content {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```css
h1 {
  color: #ff006e;
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  border: solid;
  float: left;
}

ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  margin-left:30px;
}

div>ul {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h1>Flower</h1>
<div>
  <img class="img" width="200" height="200" src="hoa.png" alt="">
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>List 1</span>
      <ul>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>E</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>List 2</span>
      <ul>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>E</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `ol` order list in the parent element

so no need to number your element manually `ol` will do the job

also margin image form the right using `margin-right` and change the inner `ul` list type to `square`

```css
h1 {
  color: #ff006e;
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  border: solid;
  float: left;
  margin-right:30px;
}

ol ul{
margin-left:170px;
list-style-type:square;
}
```

```html
<h1>Flower</h1>
<div>
  <img class="img" width="200" height="200" src="hoa.png" alt="">
</div>
<div>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <span>List</span>
      <ul>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>E</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>List</span>
      <ul>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>E</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```